# menu mobile show up even i in desktop mode in Newspaper Theme

Tags: menus, themes, mobile, responsive

I have WordPress website with **Newspaper Theme** and I have a problem with  the Menu.

Link: [demo2.tmanow.net](http://demo2.tmanow.net)

**I have 2 problems:**

1. The menu mobile show up in left side even i in desktop mode, this
   not should be displayed,just if i in mobile mode...
2. From my mobile the menu also open autumaticlly and this not good..

I tried to play some hours with the Css, but the problem still exist..

**how can i fix that ?**

regards,
Tomer.
[image]

Comment: if you have two accounts please merge them. Do not try to edit questions by one account from another account

Comment: The URL is dead so can't actually see it.

Answer (score 0):

[image: screenshot.]

Hi,

For question #1 I don't see the menu on desktop as you described.

For question #2 the menu looks very weird and I can't think of a quick solution. What did you use to create the menu? Is is the default theme menu?